# Swift: Nested dictionary remove all matching keys

Tags: swift, dictionary, nested, dplyr

I need a dictionary extension that can remove all matching keys from an arbitrary dictionary (`[String: Any]`).

An example use case could look like this:

#### Remove all keys from the given dictionary that match one of the following: `["test", "staging"]`

```
[
"foo":  [ "bar": "tralala" ]
"test": [ "foo": "bar", "staging": "hi"]
"aaa":  [ "bbb": "cccc", "staging": "jjj"]
]
```

Intended result:

```
[
"foo": [ "bar": "tralala" ]
"aaa":  [ "bbb": "cccc"]
]
```

Comment: What would be the intended result of the above?

Comment: I've added a better example.

Comment: Can you remove a single key/value pair from a dictionary? Can you iterate over the elements of an array?

Answer (score 1):

*It is not clear what **you** tried and where you got stuck, you really should include this – not doing so will be why you've been down voted.*

However, let's see if we can help. You state your dictionary is of type `[String:Any]` and do not give any nesting limit, so we'll use the following test data:

```
let sampleDict : [String:Any] =
[
   "foo":  [ "bar": "tralala" ],
   "test": [ "foo": "bar", "staging": "hi"],
   "staging" : 3,
   "one" : [ "two" : [ "three" : 3, "staging" : 4.2]],
   "aaa":  [ "bbb": "cccc", "staging": "jjj"]
]
```

If our algorithm copes with that it should cope with anything (famous last words...).

A straightforward algorithm using pre-defined methods and avoiding loops:

1. Filter the dictionary removing any key/value pairs where the key needs to be deleted.
2. Map the values in the filtered dictionary, for any value which is itself a `[String:Any]` dictionary recursively apply this algorithm to the value.

In Swift:

```
func removeMatchingKeys(_ dict : [String:Any], _ keysToRemove : [String]) -> [String:Any]
{
   return dict
      // filter keeping only those key/value pairs
      // where the key isn't in keysToRemove
      .filter { !keysToRemove.contains($0.key) }
      // map the values in the filtered dictionary recursing
      // if the value is itself a [String:Any] dictionary
      .mapValues
      {  if let nested = $0 as? [String:Any]
         // value is dictionary, recurse
         { return removeMatchingKeys(nested, keysToRemove) }
         else
         // value isn't a dictionary, leave as is
         { return $0 }
      }
}
```

Testing this with the keys:

```
let sampleKeys = ["test", "staging"]
```

The statement:

```
print( removeMatchingKeys(sampleDict, sampleKeys) )
```

Produces:

```
["foo": ["bar": "tralala"], "aaa": ["bbb": "cccc"], "one": ["two": ["three": 3.0]]]
```

The above algorithm makes two passes over the data, first to filter it and then to map it. If, *and only if*, this turns out to be a performance issue you can replace the two pre-defined functions `filter` and `map` with a simple handwritten loop which combines the operations and only passes over the data once.

*Note: Above uses Xcode 10/Swift 4.2, use any other version and YMMV (i.e. syntax & pre-defined functions could easily be different) but the algorithm is still applicable.*

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for; perfect because it is applicable to even deeper nested dictionaries!

Answer (score 0):

Using `Any` as a type for the values of a dictionary is discouraged. It would be preferable, in this case, to define your dictionary as `[String : [String : String]]`.

If you **really** can't avoid using any, let's define this dictionary which has multiple *levels* of nested dictionaries:

```
let dictionary = [
    "foo" : [ "bar": "tralala" ],
    "test": [ "foo": "bar", "staging": "hi"],
    "aaa" : [ "bbb": "cccc", "staging": "jjj"],
    "d"   : [ "e": "f", "g": ["h": "i", "test": "j"]],
]
```

And declare the keys that we'd like to remove:

```
let badKeys = ["test", "staging"]
```

Here is a recursive function that removes the unwanted keys:

```
func remove(_ keys: [String], from dict: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    var filtered = dict.filter { !keys.contains($0.key) }
    for entry in filtered {
        if let value = entry.value as? [String : String] {
            filtered[entry.key] = remove(badKeys, from: value)
        }
    }
    return filtered
}
```

And you could use it like so:

```
let result = remove(badKeys, from: dictionary)
```

Which yields:

> ["aaa": ["bbb": "cccc"], "foo": ["bar": "tralala"], "d": ["e": "f", "g": ["h": "i"]]]

*(Bear in mind that a dictionary is an unordered collection, so the the results may differ in order)*

Comment: If you are going to use a loop rather than a map (which is a valid choice) why retain the two passes rather than do the key removal in the same loop (see my earlier answer)?